# No option to maximize in Anaconda Navigator Window

Tags: 20.04, anaconda

I recently switched to Ubuntu from windows. When opening anaconda-navigator the application is opened as below. There is no maximize button available. Searched multiple sites but still don't understand what is wrong.

- Ubuntu version - 20.04.2 LTS
- Type - 64 bit
- GNOME Version - 3.36.8
- Conda version - 4.10.1

Commands used to open

```
$ conda activate
$ anaconda-navigator
```

Opened Window
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: can you right click and then maximize?

Comment: no that option is not there

Comment: The problem is probably that anaconda navigator doesn't like being maximised

Comment: does it maximise on windows?

Comment: it does maximize in windows

Comment: hmmm... thats weird... What if you try opening using a graphical interface, like GNOME startup menu?

Comment: GNOME startup menu doesn't contain any icon to launch noh